Problem with Matrix Multiplication in cmdstanpy
I am trying to do a Bayesian linear regression of a target variable (pred_Factor) with the independent variable (expl_factor), where I want predictions for each category combination coming from variable cat_1 (which has 2 categories coded, 0, and 1) and cat_2 (which has 4 categories coded, 0-3).
I have used this coding:
model_formula = "pred_Factor ~ 0 + expl_factor * cat_1 * cat_2 - cat_2 - cat_1 - cat_2 :cat_1 "

code = f"""
data {{
    int<lower=0> N;              // Number of data points
    vector[N] y;                 // Response variable
    matrix[N, 3] X;              // Predictor matrix
}}

parameters {{
    real<lower=0> beta;          // Population estimate
    vector[3] b;                 // Slope coefficients for interactions
    real<lower=0> sigma;         // Error scale
}}

model {{
    beta ~ normal(1, 5);                       // Prior for population estimate
    b ~ normal(1, 5);                           // Prior for slope coefficients
    sigma ~ student_t(3, 0, 5);                 // Prior for error scale
    y ~ normal(X * (beta + X * b), sigma);  // Likelihood with interaction terms
}}


"""

stan_file = "model.stan"
with open(stan_file, "w") as file:
    file.write(code)

model = cmdstanpy.CmdStanModel(stan_file=stan_file)

data = {
    "N": len(df),
    "y": df["pred_Factor"].values,
    "X": df[["expl_factor", "cat_1", "cat_2"]].values
}

fit = model.sample(
    data=data,
    seed=20240122,
    chains=2,
    iter_warmup=1000,
    iter_sampling=4000,
    max_treedepth=12,
)

print(fit.summary())

But I keep getting this error message:
RuntimeError: Error during sampling:
Exception: multiply: Columns of m1 (3) and Rows of m2 (121) must match in size (in 'model.stan', line 18, column 4 to column 42)
Exception: multiply: Columns of m1 (3) and Rows of m2 (121) must match in size (in 'model.stan', line 18, column 4 to column 42)

I have checked the shape of X and Y and it is as expected:
Shape of X: (121, 3)
Shape of y: (121,)

I have also tried to modify the y ~ normal(X * (beta + X * b), sigma) to y ~ normal(X * (beta + X[:,1:3] * b), sigma) but still, the error persists.

Multiply X' (X transpose) instead of X
